# How to replace each value in pandas data frame with column value?

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

If I have a Pandas data frame like this:

```
    0   20   30   40   50
 1  5  NaN   3    5   NaN
 2  2   3    4   NaN   4
 3  6   1    3    1   NaN
```

How do I replace each value with its column value such that I get a pandas data frame like this:

```
    0   20   30   40   50
 1  0  NaN   30   40   NaN
 2  0   20   30   NaN  50
 3  0   20   30   40   NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC using `mul`

```
df.notnull().mul(df.columns,1).replace('',np.nan)
   0   20  30   40   50
1  0  NaN  30   40  NaN
2  0   20  30  NaN   50
3  0   20  30   40  NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) with [`np.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```
df = df.mask(df.notnull(), np.tile(df.columns, (df.shape[0], 1)))

print(df)

   0     20  30    40    50
1   0   NaN  30  40.0   NaN
2   0  20.0  30   NaN  50.0
3   0  20.0  30  40.0   NaN
```

This assumes your column labels are integers; if not, first use:

```
df.columns = df.columns.astype(int)
```